Alexa OAuth2 tokens are not working for proactive events like Alexa.Discovery.DeleteReport
I have my own Alexa skill to manage devices. In this case a door lock, which can be opened and closed via the Alexa app or an own application. Now I want to get added or deleted devices recognized by Alexa. For this I activated Send Alexa Events in the Alexa skill build permissions, fetched the client id and client secret, that are displayed there and get a token from https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token for the user, who uses my skill. This is working and I get a token response for the user id with an access_token, refresh_token, token_type and expires_in. This one is valid and I'm able to refresh the token. Now I want to proactively send updates to Alexa. For example I want to send a DeleteReport, when a device gets removed from the user's account, but the DeleteReport is not working. With a valid token I get a "401 Unauthorized". It's neither working with a new token nor with an existing refreshed token.
This is my DeleteReport request. The token in the Authorization header and BearerToken in the body are the same.
{
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer Atza|IwEBIAQe_g...',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: '{"event":{"header":{"namespace":"Alexa.Discovery","name":"DeleteReport","messageId":"<id>","payloadVersion":"3"},"payload":{"endpoints":[{"endpointId":"<device_id>"}],"scope":{"type":"BearerToken","token":"Atza|IwEBIAQe..."}}}}'
}

This is the response for my DeleteReport request:
[Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    type: 'default',
    url: 'https://api.amazonalexa.com/v3/events',
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: {
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'authorization,x-amz-access-token',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'content-length': '198',
      'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Tue, 14 May 2024 15:12:01 GMT',
      server: 'Server',
      status: '401',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload',
      vary: 'Content-Type,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent',
      via: '1.1 ea9b4db0617b5a7ae75b10916cece9b2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
      'x-amz-cf-id': '<id>',
      'x-amz-cf-pop': 'DUB56-P2',
      'x-amz-rid': '<id>',
      'x-amzn-requestid': '<id>',
      'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront'
    },
    counter: 0,
    highWaterMark: 16384
  }

